# How can I fix ValueError in object detection application?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-3.6, onnxruntime

I am trying to add bounding boxes to an image using onnxruntime and opencv to be detect objects with the [yolov2](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/tiny_yolov2) neural network. Instead, I get an error at runtime.

I converted the input image into a compatible tensor / numpy array to feed into the model. Once I knew everything worked perfectly without bugs, I added the following code to add the bounding boxes:

```py
    while True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        for x, y, w, h in pred_onnx:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            roiGray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roiColor = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        cv2.imshow("Detect", cv2.resize(img, (500, 500)))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I was expecting the image to show (green) bounding boxes. Instead, I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OnnxCV\onnxcv\object_detector.py", line 27, in <module>
    for x, y, w, h in pred_onnx:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/D3MPapQR) if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pred_onnx` array is not in the shape expected by the current code--there is some more postprocessing to do.  See [here](http://machinethink.net/blog/object-detection-with-yolo/) for details about the output.

For example, using the 30% threshold suggested by the linked post, you would loop through and filter the bounding boxes like so:

```
for r in range(13):
    for c in range(13):
        confidence = pred_onnx[0, 4, r, c]
        if confidence < 0.3:
            continue
        x = pred_onnx[0, 0, r, c]
        y = pred_onnx[0, 1, r, c]
        w = pred_onnx[0, 2, r, c]
        h = pred_onnx[0, 3, r, c]
        ...
```